# Use IntersectionObserver To Trigger Event AFTER Element Completely Passes Threshold

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I have a few `IntersectionObserver`'s set up. `observer` toggles new boxes to be made as the user scrolls down the page. `lastBoxObserver` loads new boxes as this continuous scrolling happens.

What I would like to do is change the color of a box once it leaves the threshold set in the first observer (`observer` - whose threshold is set to `1`). So, once box 12 enters the viewport, it passes through the observer, and once it has completely passed outside of the threshold for this observer and box 13 enters the observer, box 12's background changes from green to orange, perhaps.

Is there a way to make this happen? Maybe by adding an additional observer, or adding code to `observer`? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jon424/pen/NWwReEJ

**JavaScript**

```js
 const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          entry.target.classList.toggle("show", entry.isIntersecting);
          if (entry.isIntersecting) observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        });
      },
      {
        threshold: 1,
      }
    );

    const lastBoxObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      const lastBox = entries[0];
      if (!lastBox.isIntersecting) return;
      loadNewBoxes();
      lastBoxObserver.unobserve(lastBox.target);
      lastBoxObserver.observe(document.querySelector(".box:last-child"));
    }, {});

    lastBoxObserver.observe(document.querySelector(".box:last-child"));

    boxes.forEach((box) => {
      observer.observe(box);
    });

    const boxContainer = document.querySelector(".container");

    function loadNewBoxes() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        const box = document.createElement("div");
        box.textContent = `${i + 1}`;
        box.classList.add("box");
        observer.observe(box);
        boxContainer.appendChild(box);
      }
    }
```

**HTML**

```html
   <div class="container">
      <div class="box">0</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
 .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 1rem;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }

    .box {
      background: green;
      color: white;
      font-size: 4rem;
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      transform: translateX(100px);
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 150ms;
    }

    .box.show {
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .box.show.more {
      background-color: orange;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add color change logic in your first observer.

I tested with the following changes to your code,

In css, change .box.show.more to -

```
.box.more {
      background-color: orange;
}
```

In javascript -

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          entry.target.classList.toggle("show", entry.isIntersecting);
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            observer.unobserve(entry.target);
            
            if(entry.target.textContent === '13')
                      entry.target.previousSibling.classList.toggle('more');
          }
        });
      },
      {
        threshold: 1,
      }
    );
```

As you can see, the only change is that I added this part -

```
if(entry.target.textContent === '13')
    entry.target.previousSibling.classList.toggle('more');
```

I also changed the number of new div to add from 1000 to 20 for easy test.

If you want to change box 12 color as soon as box 13 enters viewport, you can simply change "threshold" from 1 to 0.

Comment: thanks for your response, and while that does work for the 13th box, I was wondering how to do this for every box so that once a new box enters the observer the box is green, and then when it moves up the screen as a newer green box is introduced below it, the first box turns color to orange, and so on for all boxes.

Comment: If I understand your requirement correctly, you can simply remove this line - if(entry.target.textContent === '13')

Comment: To avoid error for first box, you can add check to make sure entry.target.previousSibling is not null before changing colour

Comment: Jon, thanks for accepting the answer. Could you please upvote the answer also? otherwise I may not get the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>

    </head>
    
    <body>
        <style>
            .container {
                  display: flex;
                  flex-direction: column;
                  gap: 1rem;
                  align-items: flex-start;
                }
            
                .box {
                  background: green;
                  color: white;
                  font-size: 4rem;
                  text-align: center;
                  margin: auto;
                  height: 100px;
                  width: 100px;
                  border: 1px solid black;
                  border-radius: 0.25rem;
                  padding: 0.5rem;
                  opacity: 0;

                }
            
                .box.show {
                  opacity: 1;
                }
            
                .box.show.more {
                  background-color: orange;
                }
                
                .mytest{
                    border:solid 10px #000;
                    background-color: orange;
                }
        </style>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">0</div>
            <div class="sentinel"></div>
        </div>

  
  <script>
   /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70994897/use-intersectionobserver-to-trigger-event-after-element-completely-passes-thresh/71054028#71054028 */   
   const observer = new IntersectionObserver(

     (entries) => {
       entries.forEach((entry) => {
         
         if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classList.add("show");  
        }
         if (entry.boundingClientRect.top < entry.rootBounds.top) {
           /* entry is above viewport */
           entry.target.classList.add("mytest");
           observer.unobserve(entry.target);
         }  
         
              
       });
          
     },
     {
       threshold: 0, /* top is 200 below top of viewport - something for the box to scroll into*/
       rootMargin: "-200px 0px 0px 0px"
     }
   );
   
   /* last div sentinel indicates last box */
   const mysentinel = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
     var entry = entries[0];
     if (entry.isIntersecting) {
       loadNewBoxes();
     }
   },{
        threshold: 0
   });
   

      const boxContainer = document.querySelector(".container");
      const sentinel = document.querySelector(".sentinel");
      /* setup - create extra boxes, sentinel is last after boxes */
      
      loadNewBoxes();
      
      mysentinel.observe(sentinel);
   
   function loadNewBoxes() {

     for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       const box = document.createElement("div");
       box.textContent = `${i + 1}`;
       box.classList.add("box");
       box.classList.add("show");
       observer.observe(box);
       boxContainer.appendChild(box);
     }
   
     boxContainer.appendChild(sentinel);

   }
   
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

IntersectionObserver callback is async, if you scroll fast enough then some boxes will be missed. I've simplified your code. If the box/observed target is above the root top then I add a class and unobserve it. If the box is transitioning I add a class to show the box. I use sentinel to indicate the last box and to add more boxes when the sentinel hits the viewport.